# Dependence of $|K|$ and the union of the subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, vector-spaces

If $V$ is a $K$-vector space with $|K|\ge n$ and $V_1, \ldots, V_n$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $V=V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_n$, then $V=V_i$ for some $i$. 
Is there a counterexample that for $|K|< n$ it doesn't hold ?

If $K$ has characteristic zero, it follows directly from induction that one of the subspaces has to be equal to $V$. 
Some hints are appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Draw a picture of $K^2$ where $K$ is the field of $2$ elements. Then try to write it as a union of three 1-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Might be hard to find 4 distinct 1-d subspaces... :)

Comment: @ Thats just the combination of $(0,0)$ with three points respectively . $|K|=2$ but $K^2$ can be written as union of these four 1-d vector spaces , is that right ? but when $|K|\ge n$ what actually happens we don't get this property ?

Comment: @Theorem To be fair, what you're asking about was not really posed as a question above.

Comment: @ErickWong : I know but i realized that i just thought of getting more information on the problem . I apologize if that breaks the norms of MSE.

Comment: @ErickWong: Thanks adjusted to 3, did not think long enough before posting.

Comment: @Theorem What goes wrong roughly is that there are too many hyperplanes. (Write down the plane for the field with three elements to see it.) I would prove this first for the case that the $V_i$ are hyperplanes and then expand to the general case. (Don't know if this is the most effective way to do it.)